# SQL Server 2012 Joining columns from two tables into one

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in different places

the end result has to be

```
VendorName  InvoiceNumber  InvoiceTotal
```

`VendorName` is in a table called `Vendors`

`InvoiceNumber` and `InvoiceTotal` are in a table called `Invoices`

it needs to show all the vendors in the result even if the vendors dont have any invoices, display the largest invoice totals first DESC and sort the Vendor Names in Alphabetical order.

I tried to Join the Invoices into my

```
SELECT VendorName FROM Vendors
```

but I cannot figure out the syntax :/

Comment: Please post your schema.

Comment: What do you mean by *two tables in different places*? Different databases? Different servers?

Comment: You can find some good, basic SQL tutorials at [SQLZOO](http://sqlzoo.net), for example. Take a look at them, they will help you understand SQL syntax!

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to include those vendors with no invoices like so:

```
SELECT 
  v.VendorName, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors v
LEFT JOIN Invoices i ON v.Id = i.VendorID
ORDER BY i.InvoiceTotal DESC, v.VendorName ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to join the two tables on the column that relates the two tables.  Using the `LEFT JOIN` will return all of the `vendors` even if they do not have an entry in the `invoices` table:

```
select v.vendorname,
    i.invoicenumber,
    i.invoicetotal
from vendors v
left join invoices i
    on v.vendorid = i.vendorid  -- this is the column relating the two tables
order by i.invoicetotal DESC, v.vendorname ASC
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need an [`OUTER JOIN`](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-outer-joins-in-t-sql). Assuming the PK/FK is `VendorID`:

```
SELECT v.VendorName, i.InvoiceNumber, i.InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors v
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoices i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
ORDER BY v.VendorName   ASC
      ,  i.InvoiceTotal DESC
```

Comment: The OP wants to *display the largest invoice totals first* - so you should sort by `InvoiceTotal` (not `InvoiceNumber`) I believe

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT Vendors.VendorName, Invoices.InvoiceNumber, Invoices.InvoiceTotal 
FROM Vendors LEFT JOIN Vendors.VendorID on Invoices.VendorId 
ORDER BY Invoices.InvoiceTotal DESC
```

Do you want your ventors to be grouped all together, or can a vendor be in the resultset more then 1 time? You can play with SUM(Invoices.InvoiceTotal) for example to get the total of InvoiceTotals.

Comment: Why a `GROUP BY` ? I don't see that the OP is asking for just the largest `InvoiceTotal` value - he wants the output **sorted** by that column - but not grouped - no?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like :

```
select VendorName
      ,Count(InvoiceAmount) As InvoiceNumber
      ,Sum(InvoiceAmount) As InvoiceTotal
  from Vendor
  left join Invoices on Vendor.VendorId = Invoices.VendorId
 group by VendorName
 order by 3 Desc
```

Comment: Why a `GROUP BY` ? I don't see that the OP is asking for just the largest `InvoiceTotal` value - he wants the output **sorted** by that column - but not grouped - no?

Comment: Only assumed that because he never told us that the table had an aggregate field for the invoice total ... there are 4 other answer without the group by that he can chooses from.